# Is there value to going through Rudin's Principle of mathematical analysis text after you already took an introductory analysis course?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

My questions is :Is there value in going through Rudin's Principle of mathematical analysis text after you already took an introductory analysis course?

Yes I know the answer is that it depends on my goals and what I am trying to achieve. So my answer to that is I want to pursue graduate studies in "algebra" as I personally prefer algebra over analysis. But of course, you can't only be proficient in just algebra and not analysis. So a better rephrasing of my question is : if you are planning to attend graduate school and focus on algebra, does your analysis need to be at the level where you can comfortably do most problems in Rudin's text?

Comment: If you're going to grad school in the US there'll probably be course requirements for graduate level analysis, which will likely encompass and go beyond what is in baby Rudin. So there's no need to worry about reading Rudin, wait for the coursework in grad school.

Comment: Baby Rudin is an *undergraduate* texbook.  When you start graduate studies in mathematics it is wise to be fully competent in mathematics at the undergraduate level.  So if you need a review of any subject, do a review.  Working through Rudin, however, is less pleasant than most other choices and no better than those other choices.

Comment: Alternate suggestion: If working through Rudin's PMA sounds awful to you, but you have to learn grad-level analysis anyway, consider going straight to something like Folland's or Lang's books, and just backfill as necessary.